# Skip ItemDataBound event of the repeater

Tags: c#, .net, repeater, nested-repeater

Is there a way I can skip ItemDataBound event of the repeater like using `e.Handled = true` inside the event. I know RepeaterItemEventArgs does not contain a Handled property.

Actually I want to bind repeater inside a datalist's databound event due to which repeater's bound event is called twice. So on second call of the ItemDataBound event I want to skip the event.

Comment: That seems a little odd. Why are you doing this? Maybe there is a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Store a boolean flag which will have a default value of true and inside your event you should have something like this:

```
if (myFlag) {
myFlag = false;
//Content of the method
}
else myFlag = true;
```